# How to create 2 inline forms within a single Django form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In my **models.py**, I have 3 classes

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)

class OtherClub(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
```

In my **forms.py**, I am using inline formset factory to do this:

```
class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = [
            'name', 'occupation',
        ]

FamilyMemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Member, FamilyMember, fields=('name', 'relationship'))
OtherClubFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Member, OtherClub, fields=('name',))
```

However, the part where I am lost is the views. How do I actually bring the inline forms into my form variable in the view? Currently, my view looks like this:

```
def member_edit(request, pk):
    member = Member.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if not request.user == member.user:
        return HttpResponse("You do not have the permission to do that.")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        member_form = MemberForm(request.POST, instance=member)

        if member_form.is_valid():
            member = member_form.save()
            return redirect('myapp:index')
    else:
        member_form = MemberForm(instance=member)

    return render(request, 'myapp/member_edit.html', {
        'member' : member,
        'member_form' : member_form,
    })
```

Simple form handling basically, but I don't know how to bring the inline forms into the mix, and the documentation isn't helpful at all since I am dealing with 2 inline forms.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to get the view working with one fomset, then add the other. You might find the docs on [using an inline formset in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view) and [using multiple formsets in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view) useful.

Answer (score 0):

I like using django crispy forms. Please check here http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#rendering-several-forms-with-helpers for rendering multiple forms